# How to call an API endpoint in background by another API and not wait for a response?

Tags: java, spring, api, background-process

I have an API endpoint `/api1` that will make 2 service calls -

1. insertIndb(), called on certain inputs
2. verify(), called on certain inputs

I want to return the response of `insertIndb()` to the caller when they call `/api1` only and not the `verify()` call. The `verify()` call if called, the caller need not wait for the response of this call but just get something like `response in process`. Since the goal of `verify()` is to update db and not return back anything.

So I was suggested to make this `verify` call in background. How can I do that?

**Summarizing my flow below:**

1. Enduser send POST `/api1` with payload entity.
2. If entity does not exist,

   - the `/api1` will make a `insertIndb()` call and return the response to the end user as 200.
   - After this, It will call `/verify` in background, the enduser need not wait for the response. // How to do this?
3. If entity exists,

   - It will only call `/verify` in background, the enduser need not wait for the response. // How to do this?
   - Probably return just 200 on your request is submitted.

How to run the above `/verify` calls in background based on the above flow is my question. Could anyone please help me here?

Comment: Try `CompletableFuture` and its `supplyAsync` methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to may a non-blocking fire-and-forget call like this.

The simplest, IMO, is to use a separate thread to execute the call using a synchronous operation.  Another is to use tooling that supports non-blocking calls.

In addition, there are frameworks that simplify this effort.  Camel comes to mind.  Of course, there is a fair amount of effort to use the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using @EnableAsync annotation in spring by following way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
       SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
    }
}
```

then you need to mark the emailUserInTheBackground method with @Async annotation.

```
@Service
class AnotherService {

    @Async
    public void verify(int userId) {
       try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
          System.out.println("Print from async: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Now add one more logger after a method call, you'll see getUsers(...) call completing first in a different thread even though the emailService thread is blocked for 10 seconds.

```
anotherService.verify();
System.out.println("Print from service: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Also, there is CompletableFuture for achieving non blocking coding . You can read more about this in below link
https://www.javatpoint.com/completablefuture-in-java